# Set priority for all queries of a specific Mysql user

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL instance with several schemas. My system access all the schemas using a single user. But, each schema has a specific user that is used by partners to integrate their systems using SQL.

I want that all the queries executed by that partners users run with low priority comparing with the queries of my system user.

How can I create a user that have all its queries runnig with low priority using Mysql?

Comment: There's no such functionality in MySQL

Comment: Query priority in MySQL is not something that really works any more. It used to be quasi-supported for MyISAM but has since been basically phased out. [`LOW_PRIORITY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) is a request that goes ignored.

Comment: @tadman Are you sure?I read in the 5.7 docs "If you use the LOW_PRIORITY keyword, execution of the INSERT is delayed until no other clients are reading from the table."

Comment: That applies only to MyISAM as far as I know, and I've never found it to work very well: "`LOW_PRIORITY` and `HIGH_PRIORITY` affect only storage engines that use only table-level locking (such as MyISAM, MEMORY, and MERGE)" but also "`LOW_PRIORITY` should normally not be used with MyISAM tables because doing so disables concurrent inserts". So it's basically useless. Since MyISAM is a terrible engine to start with, this is just further condemnation.

Comment: @tadman I was thinking HIGH_PRIORITY on my queries, that runs with my system user. But as you explained, the result will not be as I expected.

Comment: May as well yell at the wind at this point, MySQL won't care. You may need to do some application-level hackery with `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to see how contested your database is before launching queries or use replication to make a read-only copy you can hammer at will.